# Can FASTER be (easily) used as an ACID database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, acid

I'm trying to explore https://github.com/Microsoft/FASTER and I'm wondering if it could be used as an ACID database somehow easily.

The problem I'm unsure how to solve easily at the moment is how to "discard" a transaction if a single operation in it fails. Suppose I have a transaction in which I want to update values of 2 different keys *key1* and *key2* to *value1* and *value2*.

I need to do 2 consecutive Upserts

```
using var session = store.NewSession(simpleFunctions);

var r1 = await session.UpsertAsync(ref key1, ref value1);
while (r1.Status == Status.PENDING)
   r1 = await r1.CompleteAsync();

if (r1.Status != Status.Ok)
   Fail1;

var r2 = await session.UpsertAsync(ref key2, ref value2);
while (r2.Status == Status.PENDING)
   r2 = await r2.CompleteAsync();

if (r2.Status != Status.Ok)
   Fail2;

await store.TakeFullCheckpointAsync(CheckpointType.Snapshot);
await session.WaitForCommitAsync();
```

The problem here is what should I do in `Fail2`? `Fail1` is trivial - nothing changed so far, no rollback of anything needed. But if `Fail2` happens, I've already changed *key1* and need to rollback, otherwise the data is not consistent.

Normally, with an ACID database we could do something like:

```
try
{
    var transaction = db.BeginTransaction();

    if (!transaction.Upsert(...))
       throw ...

    if (!transaction.Upsert(...))
       throw ...

    db.Commit();
}
catch
{
    db.Rollback();
}
```

I'm not sure how to simulate that with FASTER.

Comment: You'd do it the way an actual database does it: with every operation you do you must also store (log) enough information to undo it. In this case, that means an update must be recorded with both the old value and the new value, so that you can undo the operation by setting the key back to its old value. Complicating this if you are not a database engine is that you are not the sole purveyor of the log -- if concurrent updates happen undoing the operation may be impossible, and indeed the changes would not be atomic in the sense that other transactions can see an inconsistent state.

Comment: In short, if ACID was easy and cheap, there'd be no need for anyone to use anything other than a full RDBMS, which has already solved these problems. But of course maintaining these properties comes at a price, which is why the alternatives exist in the first place. Most make concessions to the notion of full ACID to achieve higher throughput, each of which may or may not be acceptable depending on use case.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I meant whether it is possible to use FASTER in ACID way without writing the transaction rollback myself. In my use case the integrity of the data is of primary concern.

Comment: By the way, the particular pseuedo-code you provide for databases you probably wouldn't do normally. Best way to do that is without `try/catch/rollback`, and rely on the `using(var transaction` (which you don't have) to rollback the transaction

Comment: @Charlieface that's was just an example to provide a context, each DB code is different of course, some have disposable transactions, some don't ...

Comment: FASTER's model for recovery is [documented here](https://microsoft.github.io/FASTER/docs/fasterkv-recovery/). It isn't based on transactions (as indeed you wouldn't expect it to be), and it cannot support "classic" transactional logic out of the box -- doing so would basically kill its approach for performance. It really, really wants to move forward (as regular databases do too, but they support undoing in the exceptional case) so you may consider rewriting your logic that way as well (append-only, with undoing being just new updates). If that's not an option, you probably don't want FASTER.